# Combobox OnChange event not working

Tags: delphi, combobox

I had an issue with **Combobox onchange** event:
Basically if i select manually an item from combobox1 it load/write/save back the file as planned, but if i want to do the same with a loop when i hit the **UpdateBtn**, it partially work. (loop is work, and stop on last element, but not create the desired file.)

I want to do if i hit the **UpdateBtn** then the **Timer2** kick in , fire (or simulate the manual selection) the onChange event of the Combobox, and create the file as manually works.

May i missed something?

Regards

Code for the combobox1 (OnChange event, Style: csDropDown):

```
    procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
      var sl : TStringList;
    begin
     if
   ComboBox1.ItemIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('')
      then
SetCurrentDir('C:\Net-AdminUpdater\') ;
sl := TStringList.Create;
sl.LoadFromFile('Ugloader.ini');
sl[3] := 'AppPath=c:\users\'+ ComboBox1.Text +'\AppData\Local\Systemica';
sl[5] := 'LASTUPGRADE=';
sl[10] := 'AppPath=c:\users\'+ ComboBox1.Text +'\AppData\Local\Systemica';
sl[12] := 'LASTUPGRADE=';
sl[17] := 'AppPath=c:\users\'+ ComboBox1.Text +'\AppData\Local\Systemica';
sl[19] := 'LASTUPGRADE=';
sl[24] := 'AppPath=c:\users\'+ ComboBox1.Text +'\AppData\Local\Systemica';
sl[26] := 'LASTUPGRADE=';
sl[31] := 'AppPath=c:\users\'+ ComboBox1.Text +'\AppData\Local\Systemica';
sl[33] := 'LASTUPGRADE=';
sl[38] := 'AppPath=c:\users\'+ ComboBox1.Text +'\AppData\Local\Systemica';
sl[40] := 'LASTUPGRADE=';
sl[45] := 'AppPath=c:\users\'+ ComboBox1.Text +'\AppData\Local\Systemica';

SetCurrentDir('C:\Users\'+ ComboBox1.Text +'\WINDOWS\');
sl.SaveToFile('Ugloader.ini');
sl.LoadFromFile('Ugloader.ini');

sl.Free;

end;
```

Timer2 (Enabled =false by default,interval 50):

```
ComboBox1.ItemIndex := (ComboBox1.ItemIndex + 1)
```

UpdateButton(UpdateBtn) (to do the loop):

```
procedure TForm1.UpdateBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Timer2.Enabled := True;
```

Comment: In general, it is often a **bad** idea to try to change a property of a component inside an event which is triggered by a change of state of the component.

Comment: I know you had right, and will organise better, just still in learning phase. Couple things not clear, but instead of blame, i just try to find on diff sites, but now running out from ideas.

Comment: Please don't tell us to ignore the question, or not to downvote. Voting here is primarily concerned with encouraging better quality content. We aren't swayed by posters exhortations, and if anything they tend to make it more likely you will receive downvotes.

Comment: Sorry for it, question edited.

Comment: event handlers are typically for responding to UI events, like mouse clicks, not code that makes silent changes "under the hood" so to speak. Some controls do trigger events when you assign a new value to a property, but the problem is they can lead to infinite loops. They can also be hard to track down when they're not working correctly. This is not a recommended approach. Don't defend it, just come up with a different solution.

Comment: @David Schwartz i agreed, i try to understand better how things connected, and working on a better and cleaner code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as expected and as [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TComboBox.OnChange). Changing `ItemIndex` programmatically does not result in the `OnChange` event being fired. It fires only in response to user interaction.

> **Note**: OnChange only occurs in response to user actions. Changing the Text property programmatically does not trigger an OnChange event.

Extract the contents of the `OnChange` handler to a separate method and call that method from your `OnChange` handler and any code that modifies `ItemIndex`, `Text` etc.

Looking more broadly at your code, it looks like you have tied up the logic with the UI rather more than is desirable. If you want to iterate through a list of names to apply a transformation to a file, that should not involve any UI elements. You would do well to separate the logic from the UI so that your code becomes more composable.

Comment: Can you give me a head start where i am look into? i never do it before. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. Do you understand what I wrote?

Comment: write an individual handler which fire the onchange event. As you write not even possible to use the Onchange event to trigger it automatically, just manually, but if i write a different handling process it can do.  Am i right?

Comment: Yes. Whenever you change ItemIndex or Text in your code you have to manually invoke whatever other updates you want to happen.

Comment: finally i find the solution. Can 1 had a final question?

Comment: Did this answer the question you asked?

Comment: nope. Different.  Is it possible to copy a file into 2 different folder with CopyFile(PChar code snippet? Because it's only copy for 1 folder not 2.

Comment: Did this answer the question you asked? Can we deal with this question before you ask a new one on a completely unrelated topic.

Comment: Did this answer the question you asked? -No. But related to the same app (different procedure within the code.)

Comment: In what sense did this not answer the question you asked. You asked why OnChange did not fire and this answer told you.